# Nginx how to run site from another cataloge?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I try to run my site on nginx so for front I put some configuration:

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
root /var/www/domain.com/www;
index index.php;

# Use FastCGI with PHP-FPM for all things PHP
location ~ .php$ {
    fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
    include fastcgi_params;
}
}
```

And this is ok. The problem is when I try to run admin area. The admin panel is in subcataloge `/var/www/domain.com/www/admin` and there is an `index.php` file. In apache I just put another `.htaccess` file with rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|htc)$ index.php
```

and everything is ok but how to do it in nginx?

My site is build with front and admin area. The front is run when you go to domain.com/some_url.html and the admin area is in domain.com/admin/some_url.html. Catalog structure is something like that:

```
site/
    /module/
   /public_html/
             index.php
             /admin/
                  index.php
```

so when you run  domain.com/admin/ everything should be submitted to /admin/index.php but now when I go to  domain.com/admin/ the admin area are displayed but when I click some links all trafik are submitted to front index.php file.
Best Regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I get it now,

Try this

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name domain.com;
root /var/www/domain.com/www;

    location /admin/ {
      rewrite ^ /index.php?$request_uri;
    }

   # Use FastCGI with PHP-FPM for all things PHP
   location ~ .php$ {
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /var/www/domain.com/www$fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for you answare. Yes I know in nginx there is no htaccess files. Your code doesn't help because when I go to domain.com/admin/some_link.html the requests go to main index.php no to admin/index.php. There is any way to do it? The /admin/ in path should be regarded like catalog. Maybe I should create a subdomain for admin area?Best Regards.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question, if you are trying to rewrite, can you update the question with, what you want rewrite and where you want to rewrite with examples?

Comment: `index index.php;` won't rewrite, it just tells Nginx which file to load when someone access a folder. Example: if you type `domain.com/admin/` in your browser, if you have set up nginx to load `index.php` , Nginx will load `domain.com/admin/index.php` if not, Nginx will show `Forbidden` error. To rewrite you have to use `rewrite` not `index index.php;`. Update the question, I can help.

Comment: Thanks a lot for help!! Your script need a little correct but this what I need! Correct rewrite:
location /admin {
rewrite ^ /admin/index.php?$request_uri;
}